# Polar coordinates, Gauss Lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I don't understand the following statement from the Wikipedia page "Normal coordinates":

[image]

I don't see how this follows from the Gauss Lemma. The statement of the Gauss Lemma I know is:
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.
Forall $p \in M$, $x \in D_p \subset T_pM$, $v,w \in T_x(T_pM)$ it holds

$g_{\exp_p(x)} (d \exp _p(v), d \exp _p(w))=g_p(v,w)$

Now $r : U \setminus \{p\} \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ correct? Then how is even $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$ defined?

Comment: The exponential map is only a radial isometry so in the statement of the Gauss Lemma you have to assume that (under the identification $T_xT_pM\cong TpM$
) $v$ or $w$ is a scalar multiple of $x$.